# How to add new <arg> </arg> in xml file using action name in bash?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

I have .xml file which contains,

```
<action>
  <java>
   <configuration>
   ....
   </configuration>
   <main-class>main class name</main-class>
   <arg> arg1 </arg>
   <arg> arg2 </arg>
   <arg> arg3 </arg>
   <arg> arg4 </arg>
  </java>
</action>
```

Now i want to add another argument as arg5 with bash script.

I used `sed '/<arg> arg4/a <arg>arg5</arg>' XMLFile.xml`
But its giving me wrong indentations. Please let me know if there is any other ways to do it. Thnaks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `\` before the spaces:

```
sed '/<arg> arg4/a \   <arg>arg5</arg>' XMLFile.xml
```